# Contribution Receipt Comment

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions

When CiviCRM sends an email Recurring Donation Receipt below the Zip Code field there is a Comment field.
What mySqlTable stores the string that shows in the Comment associated with a recurring donation?

Comment: Can you be specific when do you get these emails? Civi send different message template for different occasion, are you referring to email when a recurring donation is created or whensomeone updates the donation?

Comment: When somebody makes a donation, or civi issues a recurring donation, both the donor and the administrator gets an email 
beginning text like:
Contribution Information
Item                               Qty Each Total
Contribution Amount 1 $ 50.00 $ 50.00
Total Amount $ 50.00
Date March 30th, 2020 8:15 PM

Comment: So I assume it is made by:
Contributions - Invoice
That can be modified from
Administer | Communications | Message Templates |
but I cannot tell where it gets the text string to put in the comment line of the message.

Answer (score 1):

By downloading the database as one file, and searching with notepad++
I found the comment in table: `civicrm_note`